# AndEngine andengine.jar file

Tags: android, android-studio, andengine, game-engine

Hi im using Android Studio ver. 0.8.6 now i want to use andEngine, i know that i should download andengine.jar file and copy it to libs folder in my project, everything is all right, but i can find the andengine.jar GLES2 there are only files with 1st version, and the newest examples didn't work with it, can someone pls give me link to andengine.jar GLES2? or maybe im doing something wrong?

I'm taking examples from official site and there are a lot of errors one of them:

`extends BaseExample`

Comment: You can make modules with the AndEngine source in Android Studio. This is preferred so you don't have to compile jars each time you update the engine code.

Answer (score 2):

AndEngine GLES2 may be downloaded [From Here](https://codeload.github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/zip/GLES2)

You can download AndEngine.jar file [From Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/andengine/andengine.jar.zip)

You can download other types of AndEngine.jar file [From Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/andengine.htm)

Also here are some examples about AndEngine [From Here](https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/lib/andengine.jar?r=af89d8cc71ca5d8ff399ee3d11035a24fbc938f9)

AndEngine GLES2 may be downloaded Alternatively [From Here](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/tree/GLES2-AnchorCenter)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/tree/GLES2-AnchorCenter Use this link to get the latest andengine also download the physics engine which is a separate jar.

Comment: Using JARs is no longer recommended.

Answer (score 1):

> or maybe im doing something wrong?

Yes. First of all, you should not be using JARs anymore. You should add AndEngine and any extension as an Android Library project (Eclipse terminology) or Module (Android studio terminology).

---

UPDATE: Since the Android Studio became the official IDE for Android, it is now recommended to use it. However AndEngine stopped being developed by its author and its populatity is on decline. Anyway see a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16588064/1667977) to add the module/library project to your game.

Comment: "You should not be using JARs anymore" There is still validity in the question. I use AIDE to code. I cloned the Andengine git repo and imported Andengine as a library to my app project and it started saying that the x86 .so files were corrupted.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan The JARs that are downloadable from old project pages were never recommended since the author published the code. They were not up-to-date.

Comment: I am up voting simply because this is true. Anyway, if anyone reading this comment is having the same problem see [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306318/rendering-sprites-using-texture-region-andengine?noredirect=1#comment48736014_30306318), as I have posted what method I used to solve the problem in an update. The [recent]solution has allowed me to begin using Andengine via a cloned Git repo.

Answer (score 0):

As @sm4 pointed out it is recommended to simply clone the git repo. However, after cloning the repo you will experience errors in AIDE when compiling. See [my question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326699/andengine-compilation-error-using-the-cloned-git-repo-in-aide) to see why I think this happens and how to fix it.