# Andengine compilation error using the cloned Git repo in AIDE

Tags: java, android, andengine, aide-ide

I am using [AIDE](http://www.android-ide.com) to code an Android game and I want to use [Andengine](http://www.andengine.org) to code my game. I heard that [it is recommended to clone the git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833336/andengine-andengine-jar-file) since the maker doesn't compile [Java Archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format))(JAR) files anymore. However, when I clone the git repo and try to compile a simple Andengine project I get errors saying that there is a "compilation error in x86".

This means that my only option is to use the older, outdated JAR files. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Copied shamelessly from my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306318/rendering-sprites-using-texture-region-andengine?noredirect=1#comment48736014_30306318)!**

I managed to get the cloned repo from GitHub to work with AIDE. I have an ARM Android device, and not a x86 one (I'm not entirely sure many people have a x86 Android, do they?). This might help others having this problem:

To fix the compilation errors I went into the android.mk script that initializes the building of the machine code for Andengine. I commented out the x86 and ran my app with a basic Andengine project and it worked. Apparently it was trying to build x86 machine code for my ARM device.

I now have access to the full power of Andengine and can finally trash that crappy, outdated .JAR I had been using until now. This opens up many tutorials for me to use.